# curl_exec is not able to identify json string and crashes the api

Tags: php

My code is as shown below:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response;
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($response['status'] == 200) { 
  echo '<img style="text-align:center"; src="./check-successful.gif" width="100" /><br/><p>Please close the browser</p>';
    sleep(2);
} 
else {
    echo '<img style="text-align:center"; src="./icn-failed-1.gif" width="100" /><br/><p>Please close the browser</p>';
    sleep(2);
}
```

Here echo gives me this output:

```
{"status":"200","message":"Your test message"}
```

but somehow , it is not identifed by `if($response['status'])` and goes into else statement only.

Comment: is the response a string? You might need to json_decode it

Comment: So "crashes the api" is just hyperbole then? And what's the thought process behind blaiming curl_exec for not implicitly decoding? Was it documented as  anything more but a request client anywhere?

Comment: Falling into an `else` is not `crashing` anything ;) The above code is working correctly as written (just not the way you thought it would work hehe). Side note... why on earth are you using `sleep(2);` in there? Surely you do not want that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decode this response with `json_decode`:

`$response = json_decode($response, true);`

Now you can use `$response` as array

Answer (score 1):

you need to decode it first, check my code:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response;
$decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($decodedResponse['status'] == 200) { 
  echo '<img style="text-align:center"; src="./check-successful.gif" width="100" /><br/><p>Please close the browser</p>';
    sleep(2);
} 
else {
    echo '<img style="text-align:center"; src="./icn-failed-1.gif" width="100" /><br/><p>Please close the browser</p>';
    sleep(2);
}
```

everything  should be just fine now.